# Device translation along axes android

Tags: android, translation, translate-animation

I pinned a picture to the wall, or to the table, or smth else. when I ROTATE phone, everything is alright, picture stays at the same place. But when I move the device from right to left (left to right) or up-bottom and vice versa, my picture moves with the camera. What should I do? My be there is some algorithm for this.
In snapchat it works very well, when you move your phone, that things, masks, flowers. etc. moves with the face, but in this case there is a face detection, which I can't use, as I pin pictures on the objects, like tables, walls, floor.

Comment: I think, you need to add something like screenshots or schemas to explain your question of what is wrong, or right

Comment: I can't put an image here..
Look, for example. there is a cycle at the center of my screen. When I move my phone from up to down, I want my cycle moves up, but it moves with the screen, it still is in the midlde of my screen

Comment: you should be able to put an image. If you are not, then upload an image somewhere, and post a link.

Comment: ok, you can use accelometer for that.

Comment: accelerometer changes also while rotatition, I don't want that. for rotation I am using game rotation vector. 
I need something, which will change only with the translation
I need something, that is used in panorama apps.

Comment: http://expirebox.com/download/24f2c7f086f1c00bbed1657a833db9d5.html
here is the image

Comment: it is what happens now.
And what I need is that cycle be not visible at the screen, as I moved my phone much to the right.
But for now, it stays at the same place on the screen